# Java: String equals not working for innerHTML text

Tags: java, string, selenium, equals

I am using Selenium in java for testing a search wizard where I need to click on a current date. I am trying to traverse through all the dates in the calendar and if matches the current date, I click it.

The problem here is that the dates are hidden so I have to get the `innerHTML` attribute, then extract the date number using substring and then comparing it with `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` but my condition is failing every time. Have tried `str.trim()` and also tried to remove all the unicode characters but nothing worked. Below is the code:

```
WebElement day_of_month = AutoUtils.findElementByTagName(day, "span");
if(day_of_month!=null){
        String innerHtml = day_of_month.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        // innerHtml is "23<span class="buzz-message">Great price</span><i></i>"
       // where 23 is the date i need

        String exact_date = innerHtml.substring(0,innerHtml.indexOf("<span"));
        exact_date = exact_date.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", ""); // have also tried exact_date.trim();
        if(exact_date.equals(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))){
                    day_of_month.click();
        } else{
             System.out.Println("not found");  //gets printed every time
        }
}
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Did you check the return type of `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`? I believe its a calendar instance. So you should type cast before you compare.

Comment: ah. I see. That's an int.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the int value (day of month) to String:

```
if (exact_date.equals(String.valueOf(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)))) {
...
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I missed the return type.

Answer (score 1):

try using innerText instead of innerHTML . innerText only gives you what is visible to the user . innerHTML gives even html and javascripts inside it.
You should be able to get "23" only and do a easy comparison.

Also, if  you can show the html , it might be easy for us to help you .